# Apply a list for 3 ways frequency table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a 3 ways frequency table, I want to combine them into a list, normally I write `listOfTable <- list(table[,,1],table[,,2],table[,,3],table[,,4],table[,,5])`, sometimes my table is really long, there is any way I can apply `lapply` to combine as a list without doing manually.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(c("A","B","C"),5)),
             N = c(rep(c("1","2","3"),5)),
             M = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3),rep(5,3)))
applyAlist <- table(df$ID,df$N,df$M)
listOfTable <- list(applyAlist[,,1],applyAlist[,,2],applyAlist[,,3],applyAlist[,,4],applyAlist[,,5])
```

Comment: `sapply(1:5, function(i) list(table[,,i]))` FYI,  `data.table` has nothing to do with `table` (I removed the tag)

Comment: @Sotos, that's quick thanks a lot

Comment: Or you can use `lapply` i.e. `lapply(1:5, function(i) applyAlist[,,i])`

Comment: @akrun, so when we use lapply, not use list()

Comment: @BIN With `sapply`, the default option is `simplify = TRUE` so it could convert to a `matrix` if we don't change to `FALSE` (when the elements have the same length), but `lapply` always returns a `list`.

Comment: @Sotos, I tag data.table just want to know there is another way to use data.table package, not necessary just for data frame, so I can know both ways

Comment: If you are planning on using data.table methods then you should realize that the applyAlist object has 3 dimensions and data.tables only have 2. You should indicate how you expect to deal with that concern ... as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply` by looping through the sequence of the third dimension and subsetting the 'applyAlist' based on the sequence.

```
lapply(seq(dim(applyAlist)[3]), function(i) applyAlist[,,i])
```

As the OP wants a `list` output, `lapply` always gives that output.  With `sapply`, the default option is `simplify = TRUE` so it would return a `matrix` or `vector` when the `length` of the elements are the same in case we did not change the option to `simplify = FALSE`.  In cases where the `list` elements are of different `class`es, this will become more noticeable and is damaging.

```
lst <- list(a = 1:3, b = rep(letters[1:3], 2), c = 2:4)
lapply(lst, unique)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$c
#[1] 2 3 4

sapply(lst, unique)
#      a   b   c  
#[1,] "1" "a" "2"
#[2,] "2" "b" "3"
#[3,] "3" "c" "4"
```

but,

```
sapply(lst, unique, simplify = FALSE)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$c
#[1] 2 3 4
```

gives similar results as `lapply` as we changed the `simplify`

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do it,

```
sapply(1:5, function(i) list(applyAlist[,,i]))
```

Comment: Except his code doesn't create an object named `table`.